# SQL Query - Combine rows based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, rows

[image]

On the image above, I'd like to combine rows with the same value on consecutive days.
Combined rows will have the earliest date on **From** column and the latest date on **To** column.
Looking at the example, even if Rows 3 and 4 have the same value, they were not combined because of the date gap.

I've tried using LAG and LEAD functions but no luck.

Comment: tag your database name

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: is it mysql,sqlserver,postgrey or oralce or else

Comment: okay. got it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try below way -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=45e47936570b74bccffe165587584bf2)**

```
    with c as
    (
    select *, datediff(dd,todate,laedval) as leaddiff,
    datediff(dd,todate,lagval) as lagdiff
    from
    (
    select *,lead(todate) over(partition by value order by todate) laedval,
    lag(todate) over(partition by value order by todate) lagval
    from t1
    )A
    ) 



select * from
(
select value,min(todate) as fromdate,max(todate) as todate from c
    where coalesce(leaddiff,0)+coalesce(lagdiff,0) in (1,-1)
    group by value
    union all
    select value,fromdate,todate from c
    where coalesce(leaddiff,0)+coalesce(lagdiff,0)>1 or coalesce(leaddiff,0)+coalesce(lagdiff,0)<-1
)A order by value
```

OUTPUT:

```
value   fromdate            todate
1       16/07/2019 00:00:00 17/07/2019 00:00:00
3       21/07/2019 00:00:00 26/07/2019 00:00:00
2       18/07/2019 00:00:00 18/07/2019 00:00:00
2       20/07/2019 00:00:00 20/07/2019 00:00:00
```

Comment: Sorry, after some testing, I encountered a problem when changing values of Rows 9 and 10 to "1". It does not return the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to recommend the following approach:

1. Find where each new group begins.  You can do this by comparing the previous maximum `todate` with the `fromdate` in this row.
2. Do a cumulative sum of the starts to define a group.
3. Aggregate the results.

This can be handled using window functions and aggregation:

```
select value, min(fromdate) as fromdate, max(todate) as todate
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_todate >= dateadd(day, -1, fromdate)
                      then 0   -- overlap, so this does not begin a new group
                      else 1   -- no overlap, so this does begin a new group
                 end) over
                 (partition by value order by fromdate) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   max(todate) over (partition by value
                                     order by fromdate
                                     rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                    ) as prev_todate
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
 group by value, grp
 order by value, min(fromdate);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a766fcbb0d17a1e79c5c0fc801181acf) is a db<>fiddle.